# Extending service base that has injected dependencies

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I've splitted my functionality into ServiceBase, that does basic operations, and the actual services, that have specific functionality. ServiceBase needs to use some common service, and specific services need to use their specific services.

So I have the ServiceBase :

```
export class ServiceBase {
  constructor(private commonService: CommonService){}
}
```

and now I have a problem, because I need to extend ServiceBase and inject some other service. I've tried:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService extends ServiceBase {
  constructor(private commonService: CommonService, private dedicatedService: DedicatedService) {
    super(commonService)
  }
}
```

but I get error, that I overwrite the definition of commonService.

On the other way, the following won't compile because I need to call super with commonService:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService extends ServiceBase {
  constructor(private dedicatedService: DedicatedService) {
    super()
  }
}
```

How do I correct handle with such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove "private" on commonService in child and make commonService in parent protected. So it will looks like:

```
export class ServiceBase {
  constructor(protected commonService: CommonService){}
}

@Injectable()
export class MyService extends ServiceBase {
  constructor(commonService: CommonService, private dedicatedService: DedicatedService) {
    super(commonService)
  }
}
```

And you still can use commonService in child class via this.commonService.